# Variables in callback function wont update even when the loop reiterates

Tags: python, ros

The task I am currently working on is:
A robot that is installed with a LIDAR sensor and placed in an enclosed warehouse. The robot initially is placed at any random position in the environment. My task is to guide the robot around the warehouse using the values from the sensor, such as wall following etc.
The problem I am facing currently is that I need the robot to start at a position before it does the wall following task. This position is such that the robot first needs to get close to the nearest wall and place itself parallel to the wall, ready to begin the wall following.

I created two '.py' files, a server file and a client file.
The client file calls the server file to do the wall search task. Once the task is complete the rest of the code in the client file is to begin the wall following. I included the code with the problems in it.
`msg.ranges[360]`  (value of front laser range) is the variable that I need help with.

```
# The lidar sensor has a range form 0 to 180 degress with index range 0-720. The laser at 360 is the front laser or the laser with 0 angle.
# The laser at 0 and 719 are at -90 and 90 angle. 

#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from rosject.srv import findwall, findwallResponse #custom service message

def callback(msg):
    r = list(msg.ranges)
    minimum_value = min(r)
    print(minimum_value)
    index_minimum = r.index(minimum_value)
    ray_angle = msg.angle_min + (index_minimum * msg.angle_increment) 
    #The distance and angle of an obstacle with respect to the laser scanner device must be calculated using 
    #The fields angle_min and angle_increment: ray_angle
    print(ray_angle)

#Logic for duration of rotation 
    countdown_sec1 = 0
    if ray_angle < 0:
        twist_instance.angular.z = 0.2 #angular velocity in radians/second
    else:
        twist_instance.angular.z = -0.2
    
    rotation_duration = (abs(ray_angle)/0.2) - 1
    
    while countdown_sec1 <= rotation_duration:
        pub.publish(twist_instance)
        rate.sleep()
        countdown_sec1 = countdown_sec1 + 1

 #Once the robot faces the wall it is stopped
    twist_instance.angular.z = 0
    twist_instance.linear.x = 0
    pub.publish(twist_instance)
    rate.sleep()

    print('front distance',msg.ranges[360]) #once stopped, I print the range of the front laser facing the wall
#This is where I faced the problem. the value that prints for the front laser is incorrect. I am unable to understand why.

#The following code is just to move the robot forward until it's within a certain distance from the wall. 

    difference = 0.3
    forward_duration = round(difference/0.1)
    countdown_sec2 = 0
    twist_instance.linear.x = 0.1
    twist_instance.angular.z = 0
    while countdown_sec2 <= forward_duration:
        pub.publish(twist_instance)
        rate.sleep()
        countdown_sec2 = countdown_sec2 + 1
    twist_instance.linear.x = 0
    pub.publish(twist_instance)
    print('final distance', msg.ranges[360]) #Even here once the task is complete the the final value remains the same and incorrect. 
# I let the callback run again and even then the value for the front laser does not change

def my_callback(request):
    print('i am working boy')
    my_response = findwallResponse()
    my_response.wallfound = True
    return my_response
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('findwall_node')
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)    
    sub = rospy.Subscriber('/scan', LaserScan, callback)
    twist_instance = Twist()
    rate = rospy.Rate(1)
    my_service = rospy.Service('/find_wall', findwall, my_callback)
    rospy.spin()
```

Where am I going wrong, why wont the value for `msg.ranges[360]` not change when the loop is run again by `rospy.spin()`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you reduce your problem down to something simpler?  Code of this length that is accompanied only by the question "why isn't my code working?" is out of scope for SO.  This is especially true of code that can't be run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am not sure how much simpler should I try to frame the question. Could you please explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msg` won't change as you're still inside `callback(msg)`. In your code, `callback(msg)` will be called everytime `sub` will receive a LiDAR scan message.

I suggest that you separate the code that receives the message from the code that waits and publishes, as you will lose laser scan messages if your node is still processing a `msg`.

Here is a way to do it in ROS1:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Int64, String


class MyNode:

    # CLASS_VARIABLES

    def __init__(self, start_value=0):
        # INSTANCE_VARIABLES
        self.counter = start_value
        pass

    def counter_callback(self, msg):
        counter_data = msg.data
        self.counter += counter_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node("my_node")
    rate = rospy.Rate(2)

    node = MyNode()
    sub = rospy.Subscriber("mynode_pub_topic", Int64, node.counter_callback)
    string_pub = rospy.Publisher("mynode_pub_topic", String, queue_size=10)

    string_instance = String()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        string_instance.data = str(node.counter)
        string_pub.publish(string_instance)

        rate.sleep()
```

Other improvements could be to use publisher and subscribers as class attributes, as [it is now done in ROS2](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html).

Comment: Just as a note, having subscribers as class attributes isn't novel to ROS2 and should still be done in ROS1.

Comment: Oh yes, I found a resource on this :https://roboticsbackend.com/oop-with-ros-in-python/. It's just that's not how they introduce newcomers to ROS1 in the tutorials. ROS2 tutorials are more explicit on using OOP in Python

Comment: This I understood but because I have some idea of OOP. I haven't come across OOP yet and will be covered in later units, so I wasn't sure if I had to use OOP for this. Infact, I have been asked to solve this before I move to next unit and the next unit is OOP. Could there be any other way to solve without OOP? Thank You.

Comment: You could use global variables, but that's a terrible way to program